# Como colocar no centro 02 TextView do VideoView

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Tenho 02 TextView e quero coloca-los no centro de uma VideoView sendo que um texto ficara um em cima do outro.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="30º C"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/Temperatura" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notícias regionais"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:id="@+id/Notícia" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode definir isso em um **LinearLayout** por causa da necessidade de definição de orientação dele. Troque o LinearLayout por um **RelativeLayout** e adicione os atributos nos 2 textViews:

```
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

faça da seguinte maneira:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/videoView" />
<TextView
    android:text="30º C"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:id="@+id/Temperatura"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<TextView
    android:text="Notícias regionais"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:id="@+id/Notícia"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Em adição, adicione o atributo android:paddingTop="50dp" no último TextView para que um texto não fique encima do outro.

Answer (score 0):

> Você pode usar o RelativeLayout e colocar o atributo nos textview
>   android:layout_centerInParent="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="text view 1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="text view 2" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```